# Masonry in materializecss

Tags: css, masonry, materialize

I would like to know if there is any way to have materializecss cards in a masonry-like display. I would like to avoid plugins like masonry, or having to compile sass, because this will be used on an aurelia application, and the configuration of external libraries and such pains me dearly.

The closest thing I have come across is this: http://codepen.io/mike-north/pen/MwVoYp?editors=1100, which does so through:

```
.cards-container {
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  .card {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

Alas, I have been unable to get it to work using a sass to css compiler. The problem is the card reveals are broken, [such as can be seen in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kajza.png). Other methods I have tried result in the same: broken cards. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

```css
.cards-container {
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}
.cards-container .card {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cards-container {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .cards-container {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .cards-container {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <h2 class='text-center'>Multi-column <a href="http://materializecss.com">MaterializeCSS</a> card flow</h2>
      <h4 class='text-center grey-text lighten-3'>
        By <a href="https://twitter.com/michaellnorth">@MichaelLNorth</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 cards-container">
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
           
           <p>This card has some extra info, which will make it taller. This is OK because we're using CSS columns!!!</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
           <p>This card has some extra info, which will make it taller. This is OK because we're using CSS columns!!!</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
           <p>This card has some extra info, which will make it taller. This is OK because we're using CSS columns!!!</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
           <p>This card has some extra info, which will make it taller. This is OK because we're using CSS columns!!!</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
         <div class="card-content white-text">
           <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
           <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
             I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="card-action">
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
           <a href="#">This is a link</a>
         </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

LOOK AT this man this is working yayayayayay.....

Comment: but it has materialize css inside it
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" />

sorry for this comment

Comment: use it as you want

Comment: These cards do not have reveal, so I do not know if it solves my problem. Plus, this is just what I said I have already done and did not work, taking the codepen and compiling the sass into css. Please read the full question before posting.

Comment: hey what do you mean by reveal, do you have a live example, please explain the issue, i think m not getting that correctly

Comment: if you have any image for explaining, means what now and what you want then it will be really helpful

Comment: you can do this by paint

Comment: I have tried all of those. Look at the picture in the question which has the described error.

Comment: I tried this in rails, at first it is working very well.. somehow it loads vertically when column-count is set to 3 but there is only 2 divs in it.

Comment: Hi Jacky, i think please check some margin and padding issue, it always cause this effect, i have faced it many time. Hope it will go well, else please a jsfiddle for me, i will check there

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go a different route.

I copied the grid scss file to a new one called masonry, in that file converted `.row` to `.card-container` and `.col` to .`card` removed stuff that pertained only to grids, tweaked the margins and now I can apply `s{val}` to any card within a card-container class and get the same effect as with columns.

```
<div class="card-container">
    <div class="card l4 m6 s12 sticky-action">
        // card stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if this will be perfect for you, but it does provide nice cards that flow and works great as far I can tell so far.

Here is the scss here:

```
.container .card-container {
  margin-left: (-1 * $gutter-width / 2);
  margin-right: (-1 * $gutter-width / 2);
}

// Mixins to eliminate code repitition
@mixin card-offset {
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}

.card-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  // Clear floating children
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  .card {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2%;
    min-height: 1px;

    &[class*="push-"],
    &[class*="pull-"] {
      position: relative;
    }

    $i: 1;
    @while $i <= $num-cols {
      $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i) - 4) + "%");
      &.s#{$i} {
        width: $perc;
        @include card-offset;
      }
      $i: $i + 1;
    }

    @media #{$medium-and-up} {

      $i: 1;
      @while $i <= $num-cols {
        $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i) - 4) + "%");
        &.m#{$i} {
          width: $perc;
          @include card-offset;
        }
        $i: $i + 1
      }
    }

    @media #{$large-and-up} {

      $i: 1;
      @while $i <= $num-cols {
        $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i) - 4) + "%");
        &.l#{$i} {
          width: $perc;
          @include card-offset;
        }
        $i: $i + 1;
      }
    }

    @media #{$extra-large-and-up} {

      $i: 1;
      @while $i <= $num-cols {
        $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i) - 4) + "%");
        &.xl#{$i} {
          width: $perc;
          @include card-offset;
        }
        $i: $i + 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

just compile it as normal after your cards scss

Hope it helps someone.