# Materializecss card distribution

Tags: html, css, angularjs, materialize, masonry

I am working on a website with the help of angularjs and materializecss. The problem I am facing is that I get the white space you can see below in the picture between 2 cards.

I tried this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933939/masonry-in-materializecss) solution but then the cards are sorted top to bottom and I want them to sort left to right. Is there maybe something I can do with a float? I could use masonry but I find it very hard to get it to work. Because I need to update it when I change the ng-repeat, also when images load slowly masonry doesn't do what I want.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

```
<div class="container">
<div ng-controller="featured">
    <h1>Featured</h1>
    <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="search..."/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cards-container">
            <div class="col s12 m6 l4" ng-repeat="x in data | filter:q as results" repeat-end="onEnd()">
                <div class="card" post-id="{{x.id}}">
                    <a style="display:block" href="#post/{{x.id}}">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <img ng-src="{{x.thumb}}">
                            <span class="card-title">{{x.title | limitTocustom:30}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <p>{{x.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action grey-text lighten-2" ng-animate="'animate'" style="padding:15px 15px 15px 15px !important;">
                        <div>
                            <!-- <span><span><i class="material-icons" style="margin-right:5px;">account_circle</i>{{x.author}}</span><span style="float:right;"><i class="material-icons red-text text-lighten-2" style="margin-right:5px;">favorite</i>{{x.points}}</span></span> -->
                            <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{x.author}}</span>
                            <span style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{x.points}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**First solution I found**
With this I can configure on what div I want the clearfix. So when the user is using a smaller screen it will do that with .col:nth-child(2n+1).

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 993px) {
    .col:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: both;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
    .col:nth-child(3n+4) {
        clear: both;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
    .col:nth-child(3n+4) {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Very difficult to help without seeing HTML and CSS...

Comment: You could do something like clearfix after every 3 element, since you have 3 cards in 1 row. Go through clearfix in bootstrap and you can implement it by yourself afterwards.

Comment: You can refresh masonry after you edit things with javascript. Also masonry has a async and sync method.

Comment: @Niraj that works when there are 3 cards in 1 row. But when there are 2 the trick doesnt work anymore.

Comment: @Luukth The number of cards in one row needs to be fixed in order to make clearfix work. Your cards vary in terms of number??

Answer (score 1):

```
.card{
height:300px;
}

<div class="container">
<div ng-controller="featured">
    <h1>Featured</h1>
    <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="search..."/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cards-container">
            <div class="col s12 m6 l4" ng-repeat="x in data | filter:q as results" repeat-end="onEnd()">
                <div class="card"  post-id="{{x.id}}">
                    <a style="display:block" href="#post/{{x.id}}">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <img ng-src="{{x.thumb}}">
                            <span class="card-title">{{x.title | limitTocustom:30}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <p>{{x.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action grey-text lighten-2" ng-animate="'animate'" style="padding:15px 15px 15px 15px !important;">
                        <div>
                            <!-- <span><span><i class="material-icons" style="margin-right:5px;">account_circle</i>{{x.author}}</span><span style="float:right;"><i class="material-icons red-text text-lighten-2" style="margin-right:5px;">favorite</i>{{x.points}}</span></span> -->
                            <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{x.author}}</span>
                            <span style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{x.points}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Give fixed height to your cards like this. it will solve your problem